# Auto-append dummy folder name to end of base URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Take a look at this sample vhost snippet:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /web/content
    ServerName   me.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Say */web/content* contains 2 files, *index.html* and *page.html*, and a subdirectory *colors* containing *yellow.html*. *index.html* contains links like `href="/page.html"` and `href="/colors/yellow.html"`, using `/` to refer to the web root.

Is there a way to internally use **me.example.com/test/** as the **root** of the site? In other words, when a user goes to http://me.example.com/test/, I want to fetch */web/content/index.html*. So, the */test/* in the URL would essentially be a dummy "folder".

Basically, I'd like me.example.com/test to function exactly how a subdomain (say, *test.me.example.com*) would. Something like setting `ServerName me.example.com/test` (but I know that doesn't work).

I know I could simply make a REAL folder */web/content/test* and put everything in there, but that would break my links beginning with a `/`, as they would still refer to */web/content* as the web root. The same problem arises when adding a directive like `Alias /test /web/content`.

Do I have any options here? Maybe using RewriteBase somehow? (I've tried a few things with no luck.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L]
```

This maps the `/test/` URI path to the document root. If you want to say, map it to the colors folder, you'd do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/colors/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/colors/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ /colors/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! Now I'm going home early. :)